# ¿Dónde colocar los bloques de nuevas clases creadas por mi?

Tags: c#, diseño-de-clases

Tengo una duda. Dónde colocar los bloques de nuevas clases creadas por mi en el cuerpo del propio programa C#
¿Dentro del bloque namespace, dentro del bloque Program?. ¿Donde es mejor?. Gracias.

Comment: No estaria entendiendo tu problema... a que te referis? podes dar un ejemplo? y agrega el lenguaje...

Answer (score 1):

Donde tu quieras y/o lo necesites.

Un `namespace` es una forma de organizar el código, son una especie de carpetas virtuales. Generalmente en un proyecto tu creas carpetas para organizar el proyecto, estas carpetas no tienen efecto alguno en lo que al código se refiere, por ejemplo no son relevantes cuando haces una referencia a una clase. En cambio, el `namespace` es lo importante. Puedes tener en un `namespace` distinto a tus carpetas o varios `namespace` dentro de un mismo archivo. Aunque lo habitual y lo que te recomiendo es que los `namespace` tengan una relación 1-1 con las carpetas.

Por otro lado, cuando dices "dentro del bloque Program" infiero que te refieres a la clase `Program`. En C# es posible declarar las clases dentro de otras clases, aunque  no se muy habitual su uso.

Al final todo depende del ámbito de tus clases y tiene que ver con los modificadores

- public
- private
- protected
- internal

[Aquí más información](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/access-modifiers) con respecto a eso

Por ejemplo: En C# no puedes declarar una clase privada dentro de un `namespace`, es decir, esto sería incorrecto

```
namespace ConsoleApp40
{
    private class UnaClase { }//error
}
```

En cambio si lo puedes hacer dentro de otra clase:

```
namespace ConsoleApp40
{
    class Program
    {
        private class UnaClase { }
    }
}
```

Esto te permitirá instanciar la clase solo dentro de la clase padre, pero no desde otro lado

```
namespace ConsoleApp40
{
    class Program
    { 
        private class UnaClasePrivada { }
        public class UnaClasePublica { }

        UnaClasePrivada unaClasePrivada=new UnaClasePrivada(); //Bien
        UnaClasePublica unaClasePublica=new UnaClasePublica(); //Bien
    }

    public class OtroClase
    {
        ConsoleApp40.Program.UnaClasePrivada unaClasePrivada; //Error, porque la clase es privada
        ConsoleApp40.Program.UnaClasePublica unaClasePublica; //Bien
    }
}
```

---

Ahora todo esto es un caso muy particular y se realiza solo cuando es necesario, lo habitual y me recomendación: Es que la nuevas clases la ingreses en un archivo separado, organizado en carpetas (cuando lo requieras), con el respectivo  `namespace` y dentro de él

Comment: Muchas gracias, es lo que necesitaba saber.

Comment: @guillermoflorido sería bueno que lo marques como respuesta.